# Opposite of cross-product: How to create a new matrix from the intersection of two matrices?

Tags: r, matrix, cross-product

I have two tables in R (females and males) with presence-absence data. I'd like to do pairwise comparisons between them (row-by-row) to find the number of cells not shared between each pair (i.e the sum of cells equal to 1 on the female but not on the male and vice-versa).

I know that the cross product (%*%) does the opposite of what I need. It creates a new matrix containing the sum of shared cells between pairs of males and females (i.e sum um cells equal to 1 in both).

Here is an example dataset:

```
females <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1), nrow=5, byrow=T))
males <-  as.data.frame(matrix(c(1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1), nrow=5, byrow=T))
rownames(females) <-c ("female_1","female_2","female_3","female_4","female_5")
rownames(males) <-c ("male_1","male_2","male_3","male_4","male_5")
```

So, if I do the cross product

```
as.matrix(females) %*% t(as.matrix(males))
```

I get this

```
            male_1 male_2 male_3 male_4 male_5
female_1      2      2      1      2      1
female_2      1      2      0      2      0
female_3      2      1      3      2      3
female_4      3      3      2      4      2
female_5      3      2      3      3      3
```

But I need this (only first row shown)

```
            male_1 male_2 male_3 male_4 male_5
female_1      1      1      3      2      3
.
.
```

In reality, my dataset is not symmetrical (I have 47 females and 32 males).

Thanks for any help!!!

Comment: You can see from the data frame that female_1 has "0" at position [1,1] and male_1 has "1" at position [1,1]. And of all 5 columns in the both datasets, this is the only one where there is a  "mismatch" between this pair. So, there is a total of "1" cell where this female_1/male_1 pairwise comparison fulfills my condition. Does that make sense?

Comment: It's not really an "intersection" in any sense but rather a mapping to a "product space". The two functions that deliver an n-by-m results for matrix objects are `outer` and `kronecker`, but getting them to work correctly often requires subtle crafting of code to get functions that deliver the properly dimensioned results.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, `ncol(females) - tcrossprod(!females, !males) - tcrossprod(as.matrix(females), as.matrix(males))` seems correct

Comment: @alexis_laz This works and is a very elegant way too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up an object to receive results:

```
xy <- matrix(NA, nrow(females), nrow(males))
for ( x in 1:nrow(females) ){
        for(y in 1:nrow(males) ){ 
              xy[x,y] <- sum(females[x, 1:ncol(females)] != males[y,1:ncol(males)])}}
```

Should have done with nested sapply calls as well and might have been a bit cleaner since there was no need to have a separate "setup", (but only a little bit cleaner, and contrary to popular myth not any faster):

```
 xy <- sapply( 1:nrow(females) , 
              function(x) sapply( 1:nrow(males) , 
                  function(y) sum( females[x, 1:ncol(females)] != males[y,1:ncol(males)]) ))
 xy
#-----
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    3    2    1    1
[2,]    1    1    4    1    3
[3,]    3    5    0    3    1
[4,]    2    2    3    0    2
[5,]    3    5    0    3    1

dimnames(xy) <- list( rownames(females), rownames(males) )
```

Comment: Thanks,     @42- ! Is there a way to keep the row and column names (as in the cross product example) so I can use them later?

Comment: It's pretty easy to add dimnames to a matrix. See the help page for `?dimnames`, since I'm sure that the assignment function is also described. Could also have done it in the "setup" step if using the for-loop method.

Comment: Excellent @42- ! Thanks again!

Comment: As a bit of etiquette advice. If asking for additional coding you will better motivate your respondents better if you upvote or checkmark suitable answers initially.

Comment: Alright! I'll keep that in mind for future questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
inverseCross <- function(females, males){ 
inverse <- data.frame(a=integer(), b=integer(), c=integer(), d=integer(), e=integer()) 
tempRow <- NULL
 for(i in 1:nrow(females)){
for(j in 1:nrow(males)){
sum <- 0
for(k in 1: ncol(males)){
if(females[i,k] != males[j,k]){
sum <- sum + 1
}
}
tempRow <- c(tempRow, sum)
}
inverse[i,] <- tempRow
}
colnames(inverse) <- rownames(males)
rownames(inverse) <- rownames(females)  
inverse
}
```

Comment: I doubt that would run at the moment. In R, linefeeds (or semicolons) are syntactically essential.

Comment: inverseCross <- function(females, males){  inverse <- data.frame(a=integer(), b=integer(), c=integer(), d=integer(), e=integer()) 
for(i in 1:nrow(females)){
  tempRow <- NULL
  
  for(j in 1:nrow(males)){
    sum <- 0
    for(k in 1: ncol(males)){
      if(females[i,k] != males[j,k]){
        sum <- sum + 1
      }
    }
    tempRow <- c(tempRow, sum)
    
  }
  inverse[i,] <- tempRow  
  }  
colnames(inverse) <- rownames(males)  
rownames(inverse) <- rownames(females)  
inverse
}